# Fetch unique data from db

Tags: php, mysql, unique

I've a db column named "alerts" in a table named "users" where the data of alerts for each user has been entered like;

```
UserA -> 1,2,3,4,5,6
UserB -> 33,44,22
UserC -> 333,444,555
```

The comma separated numbers are pid (Post ID)

Now I want to fetch Users having a certain "pid" e.g. 444

I'm using this query;

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE alerts LIKE '%{$pid}%'");
$uid = $db->fetch_array($query);
```

Now the issue is, it does fetch the users but NOT unique. For example if I'm searching for pid = 444 then it fetches all those users having "4" in alerts column. How should I go about searching for the unique users?

Comment: You need to normalize this data.

Comment: Must be muti-value column week.

Comment: But why -1 ? :/ english is my second language and probably that's why I wasn't able to explain the question properly..

Comment: Wasn't me, though the next time some one uses a multi-value column, I'm going to set up "user1,user2, user3, user4,.... user10000" accounts and downvote them to death...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET('{$pid}',alerts);
```

[FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: Now I don't know whether I'm happy that this facility exists, or dismayed that someone thought it should. :(

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can't fix your design to get rid of the multi-value column.

Like '4' or Like '4,%' or like '%,4,' or like '%,4' would do it.

Now you know why more experienced developers wince when they see some one has made this mistake again...